# How can I avoid this error while implementing tree with recursive data structures? "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c, data-structures, compiler-errors, tree, recursive-datastructures

When trying to do this: `g->v+i=aux;`, I get:

> ERROR: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

The `g->v` is a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of children.

Even after allocating space for the array, the compiler doesn't like it when I increment the pointer.

```
int n=5
struct group
{
    int n,x,y,exp,r;
    struct group *v;
};
void init_group(struct group *g)
{
    g->v=malloc(sizeof(struct group*)*(n));//an array of n elements
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            struct group *aux;
            g->v+i=aux; **// HERE IS THE ERROR**
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and what alternative can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `v` member is a `struct group*`, which will allow it to hold an array of *structures*; but you are allocating it (and attempting to assign it) as though it were an array of **pointers** to structures.

So – if the `malloc` call is doing what you actually want it to (i.e. creating an array of `n` pointers) – then that member should be declared as a pointer-to-pointer: `struct group** v;`.

Second, when accessing array elements, avoid confusion by not using pointer arithmetic: that's what the `[]` operator is for; a simple `g->v[i] = aux;` will do the job for you.

Here's a modified/working version of your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n = 5;
struct group
{
    int n, x, y, exp, r;
    struct group** v; // Double pointer to hold an array of POINTERS
};

void init_group(struct group* g)
{
    g->v = malloc(sizeof(struct group*) * (n));//an array of n elements
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct group* aux = NULL; // Actually give a value?
        g->v[i] = aux; // Use the array's [] operator
    }
}
```

If you really *insist* on using pointer arithmetic, rather than the `[]` operator, then (after correcting the member type to a pointer-to-pointer), the syntax is as follows:

```c
        *(g->v + i) = aux;
```